# Question about the elasticity matrix in metals

Tags: material-science, crystals, elasticity, continuum-mechanics, metals

The most general anisotropic linear elastic material has 21 elastic constants. I am working with an HCP material and I found that it has 5 independent elastic constants. I am programming a subroutine to rotate elasticity matrices. My question is, is the elasticity matrix in HCP defined in the hexagonal coordinate system? I tend to think that the answer is “yes”, and therefore, if I want the elasticity matrix in an orthogonal basis, I should apply the corresponding transformation. When we simplify from 21 elastic constants to any number according to the crystal structure in textbooks, is this usually done in the crystallographic basis?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Of course it is tied to the crystal basis - that is what defines the symmetries after all. As an aside, doing the rotations using the reduced 6x6 elasticity tensor is painful. Expanding to a 9x9 basis and rotating that is much easier.